# Why we need 64 bit installer to build 64 bit setup?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, installation

I have a 32 bit application which works fine on both 32 bit and 64 bit environment. It is built on VS2010 in "Mixed Platform" mode. Now, I have been asked to built a setup specially for X64. I dont know why we need to re-built the setup even we already have one which is working fine on X64? Why it is so ?

Comment: So this new 64-bit setup will still be installing a 32-bit program, correct? You say something contradictory - you say it's a 32-bit application but also that it is in "mixed platform" mode. If I understand you correctly, that means it will run as a 32 bit program under x86 OS bit as 64 bit under x64.

Comment: @matthew: I m sorry, But I dont know too much about building setup for different platforms. I explained the exact situation at which I am right now AND Some of my senior configure it as "Mixed Platform". 

"So this new 64-bit setup will still be installing a 32-bit program, correct?"

Yes.

"You say something contradictory - you say it's a 32-bit application but also that it is in "mixed platform" mode".

I m nt aware about "mixed paltform" provides such flexibility.
"If I understand you correctly, that means it will run as a 32 bit program under x86 OS bit as 64 bit under x64."
Ya, u r right.

Comment: I agree with Hans Passant...unless there is a specific and demonstrable need, having a second installer just for 64-bit is unnecessary.  I, for one, have never needed to do such a thing.  I think I would be questioning this _need_ and the reason(s) behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a 64-bit installer, you just need to tell the installer that you are going to install a 64-bit program.  It is rather a big deal, 32-bit programs are heavily affected by:

- Registry redirection, 32-bit programs are redirected to the SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node key
- File system redirection, most visible in that 32-bit programs are redirected to c:\program files (x86)
- Affecting your choices, you may well need to pick another EXE or DLL if it depends on the bitness.  That's primarily an issue with executables that contain unmanaged code, they need to be built differently if they are going to run on a 64-bit operating system.

The first two bullets are the ones that affect the installer the most, it needs to be aware of the bitness so it writes to the proper registry keys and directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 64 bit application running on a 64 bit operating system, you can have many advantages over the 32 bit application running on same operating system.

1 - A 64 bit application running on a 64 bit operating system can use much more memory/RAM as compared to a 32 bit application running on a 64 bit operating system

2 - In 64 bit application you can perform operations that will consume 64 registers at a time which can make your application fast as compared to 32 bit application which will consume on 32 registers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the background, but i would say that the want you to make the X64 only to get more speed on the program, a x32 can only use 3GB ram, were x64 can use a lot more..

Comment: More RAM != more speed. The only case where more RAM does imply more speed, is when your program requires it, but your system doesn't have it.

Comment: yes, that why i tell that x32 can only use 3GB ram even if you pc have 32GB (or i dont know about max and linux)

Comment: Yes, but in this case, using 3GB or 30GB doesn't necessarily make the program faster. If the PC only has 1GB RAM free and your program needs 3GB, then it'll use the storage for the remaining 2GB, which is extremely slow. But that's got nothing to do with 32bit vs. 64bit

Comment: your are totaly right.

But i hope that x64 do more than only give the availability to use more ram, but i don´t know for sure